# blank instead of zero

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Duration = isnull(FunctionA(DateA,DateB),'')
```

The Function above calculates number of days and if day is null it displays
the value 0 instead of blank value

How can I change the above code to so that it shows blank and not 0 for value null?

Comment: does FunctionA actually return a null value? If it returns a 0 when datea or dateb are null, then isnull will never trigger the `''`.

Comment: yes it does returm null values as well and it is changing null to 0 with the code above and I want blank not 0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your function returns an integer the result from `isnull` will also be an integer. In the case the return value is `null` you will have an implicit conversion to integer for '' and that will be 0.

Try this:

```
declare @xx int
select isnull(@xx,'')
```

Result:

```
-----------
0
```

You can have the space if you first cast the return value from your function to `varchar`.

```
declare @xx int
select isnull(cast(@xx as varchar(10)),'')
```

Result:

```
----------
                                                                                .
```

If your function returns `0` instead of `null` you can use `nullif` to get a null value before you cast to `varchar`.

```
declare @xx int = 0
select isnull(cast(nullif(@xx, 0) as varchar(10)),'')
```

**Summary**:

You need this:

```
Duration = isnull(cast(FunctionA(DateA,DateB) as varchar(10)),'')
```

or this

```
Duration = isnull(cast(nullif(FunctionA(DateA,DateB), 0) as varchar(10)),'')
```

Comment: Duration = isnull(cast(nullif(FunctionA(DateA,DateB), 0) as varchar(10)),'')  is correct :)

Answer (score 2):

If `Duration` is datatype `int` then you can't change that to an empty string (blank).  You'll either have to change that to a string datatype (`varchar` for instance) or be okay with `0`.  `int` can either be `NULL` (if it is allowed) or a valid integer value.  A blank string is not a valid integer value.

Comment: it is a report, so can i convert anything so that it displays blank value rather than 0?

Comment: Is this a report being made in SSRS?  If so, the expression in the text box can be set to reflect this logic, but not in the query itself as Shark stated.

Answer (score 1):

I use case statements and casting to do this.

Example:
case when columnX <> 0 then cast(columnX as nvarchar) else '' end

Basically, you're changing your numeric to show either as a character or a blank. You will have to do all your math before you change to nvarchar though, because outside of this, it becomes a string. It would be helpful if BLANK was a command and worked with numeric values though.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Is FunctionA returning 0 instead of null?  The code you've written may be ok, but if FunctionA never returns `null` then...

Comment: If FunctionA is returning 0 you could wrap the call to it with NULLIF to convert it to null when it returns 0.  Then the ISNULL should work.

Comment: ISNULL(NULLIF(FunctionA(DateA,DateB), 0),'')

Comment: ISNULL(NULLIF(FunctionA(DateA,DateB), 0),'') does not work and gives same 0 value rather than blank

Comment: yes FunctionA returning 0 instead of null and I want blank instead of 0

Comment: Then I think you need to look at Mikael Eriksson or Shark's posts; they are likely on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare Duration as a sql_variant datatype and allow implicit conversion to occur
so something like this should work

declare @DURATION sql_variant

select COALESCE(@DURATION,  '')

set @DURATION=1

select COALESCE(@DURATION,  '')